# ¿Como puedo insertar datos en dos o mas tablas al mismo tiempo?

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy usando

---

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO factura (user_id, fecha) VALUES ($userid, '$date')"; 
$sql = "INSERT INTO boleto (sala, horario, asiento, user_id)" VALUES ('$sala', '$horario', '$asiento', $userid)";

 mysqli_query ($conn, $sql);                                            
 header("Location: ../index.php?signup=success");"
```

---

Y

---

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO factura (user_id, fecha) VALUES ($userid, '$date')" AND $sql = "INSERT INTO boleto (sala, horario, asiento, user_id) VALUES ('$sala', '$horario', '$asiento', $userid)";
```

---

Pero al revisar en la base de datos, solo inserta los datos en factura o el boleto =S

Comment: Tienes que ejecutarlas aparte. Una consulta: `$sql = "INSERT INTO factura (user_id, fecha) VALUES ($userid, '$date')";  mysqli_query ($conn, $sql);`  y luego la otra: `$sql = "INSERT INTO boleto (sala, horario, asiento, user_id)" VALUES ('$sala', '$horario', '$asiento', $userid)"; mysqli_query ($conn, $sql);`  **NOTA:** Tus consultas son altamente vulnerables a ataques de Inyección SQL. Deberías implementar consultas preparadas para prevenir ese riesgo de seguridad.

Comment: It worked as you said, thank you for the information ! :)

Comment: Me alegro. Por favor, cuando sea posible l◔_◔: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) en el Centro de Ayuda. Thanks!

Comment: He editado la respuesta, agregando al final la implementación de un código seguro que previene contra ataques de Inyección SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo más conveniente es que las ejecutes aparte o que las identifiques de forma distinta.

En cualquier caso, al llamar a `mysqli_query` una sola vez, te ejecutará la consulta con el último valor en `$sql`.

Quizá se podría tratar también con [`mysqli_multi_query`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.multi-query.php), aunque no tendría gran ventaja aquí.

Bastaría con hacer esto:

```
$insertFactura = "INSERT INTO factura (user_id, fecha) VALUES ($userid, '$date')"; 
$insertBoleto = "INSERT INTO boleto (sala, horario, asiento, user_id) VALUES ('$sala', '$horario', '$asiento', $userid)";

 mysqli_query ($conn, $insertFactura);                                            
 mysqli_query ($conn, $insertBoleto);                                            

 header("Location: ../index.php?signup=success");"
```

O bien:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO factura (user_id, fecha) VALUES ($userid, '$date')"; 
 mysqli_query ($conn, $sql);                                            

$sql = "INSERT INTO boleto (sala, horario, asiento, user_id) VALUES ('$sala', '$horario', '$asiento', $userid)";
 mysqli_query ($conn, $sql);      

 header("Location: ../index.php?signup=success");"
```

---

En la segunda consulta había un error se sintaxis (`"` antes de `VALUES`).

> **NOTA:** Tus consultas son altamente vulnerables a ataques de Inyección SQL. Deberías implementar consultas preparadas para prevenir
>   ese riesgo de seguridad.

### La mejor solución

Propongo aquí un código usando consultas preparadas, para neutralizar de ese modo posibles ataques de inyección SQL.

En los comentarios he explicado los elementos esenciales de esta **muy recomendada práctica**, que conviene implementar no sin tardanza.

```
/*
    *Una variable utilitaria para ir recogiendo lo ocurrido en el flujo del código
*/
$strMensaje="";


/*
    *PRIMERA CONSULTA:
    *Dos marcadores ?,? que sustituyen a los valores reales
    *neutralizando así la inyección
*/
$insertFactura = "INSERT INTO factura (user_id, fecha) VALUES (?, ?)"; 

/*
    *Preparamos la 1ª consulta dentro de un condicional
    *así controlamos cualquier fallo en el else
*/
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $insertFactura)) {
    /*
        *Es aquí donde se pasan los valores provenientes del exterior
        *de modo que es imposible que te cuelen código malicioso
        *porque esté método te protegerá de eso precisamente
        *Aquí lo importante a comprender es que
        * - 1. Donde está esto: "is" se deben poner 
               tantas iniciales como signos ? haya en la consulta (dos en este caso)
               Esas iniciales indican el tipo de dato de la columna respectiva
               Si es un (i)nteger, si es un (s)tring, etc.
          - 2. Se escriben luego las variables (sin comillas ni nada), en el mismo orden
               en que aparecen en la sentencia INSERT de más arriba
    */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "is", $userid, $date);

    /*
        *Se ejecuta la consulta
    */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $strMensaje.="La inserción en factura fue exitosa. Filas insertadas: ".mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt).PHP_EOL;
}else{
    $strMensaje.="La inserción en factura fue errónea. Error: ".mysqli_stmt_error($stmt).PHP_EOL;

}

/*
    *SEGUNDA CONSULTA:
    *Es casi todo igual que en la 1ª
    *Cuatro marcadores ?,?,?,? que sustituyen a los valores reales
*/  

$insertBoleto = "INSERT INTO boleto (sala, horario, asiento, user_id) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";

if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $insertBoleto)) {
    /*
        *Lo mismo que se explicó antes
        *Nótese que aquí tenemos "sssi", porque en $insertBoleto hay 4 columnas
        *Las tres primeras son de un tipo string (VARCHAR), por eso las sss
        *y la última es un entero, por eso la i 
    */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssi", $sala, $horario, $asiento, $userid);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $strMensaje.="La inserción en boleto fue exitosa. Filas insertadas: ".mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt).PHP_EOL;
}else{
    $strMensaje.="La inserción en boleto fue errónea. Error: ".mysqli_stmt_error($stmt).PHP_EOL;

}

/*
    *Una vez terminado todo, imprimimos lo que se recogió en la variable utilitaria
    *Esto tiene la ventaja de que te informará de lo que ocurrió en ambas consultas
*/

echo $strMensaje;
```